# What is the commutation relation of $[ V(r, t), P]$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, commutator

I don't understand how come [ P ,  V(r, t) ] = - ih ∇V.
where P is momentum and V(R, t) is the potential.
As [ P , V(r, t) ] = P V - V P , 
i. e 
   [ P , V(r, t) ] = - ih ∇V + ih V∇.

Comment: Apply it to a test function

Answer (score 3):

You should use the differentiation rules of a function composition, since your potential operator depends on coordinate vector. Since at the end your commutator is an operator, imagine you are acting with it on some wave function, then:
$$\Big[\hat{p},\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\Big]\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)=\Big\{\hat{p}\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\Big\}\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)-\Big\{\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\hat{p}\Big\}\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)=\\=(-i\hbar\nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}})\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)-\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)(-i\hbar\nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}})\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)=-i\hbar\Big\{\nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}}\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\Big\}\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)-i\hbar\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\Big\{\nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}}\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)\Big\}-(-i\hbar)\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\Big\{\nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}}\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)\Big\}=-i\hbar\Big\{\nabla_{\boldsymbol{r}}\hat{V}(\boldsymbol{r},t)\Big\}\psi(\boldsymbol{r},t)$$

Comment: Thanks!! Got it, i should have used little basics.